# what's the difference between find, findAll and findQuery in ember-data

Tags: ember-data

What is the difference between find, findAll and findQuery in ember-data?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`find` is a convenience wrapper for `findAll`, `findQuery` and `findById`.

- `findAll` will return all the records of a specific type (this will trigger a request to the server) `all` is basically the same but uses the cache, so if you have records in your store, no request will be made
- `findQuery` is to return a subset from your server
- `findById` returns a single object

https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L431

Comment: Thanks, I now see where find changes to findQuery if the id argument passed in is a object.

Comment: Thanks, that helps me a lot !